Strange error when deploying Experience Cloud Site related to user 8renmai?
We are receiving a strange error when deploying Experience Cloud Site
Error <ExperienceCloudSiteName> Cannot find a user that matches any of the following usernames: <user@name.com>.<sandbox>, 8renmai<user@name.com>.<sandbox>, <user@name.com> ; remove the user from the component being deployed or create a matching user in the destination organization.    

We don't have user@name.com mentioned in /experience/ folder or anything else.
Deployment is performed under different user. user@name.com. does exist in the target org. What might be the problem?

The problem was related to Site Domain not being setup on the target sandbox.
Once Site Domain is established, the issue has magically resolved.



We deploy Exp sites without site domain all the time..

really? and you don't experience any issues like this?

Not this issue, no
